# SageMaker Inference for a video input

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I wonder if it's possible to run SageMaker Inference or Batch Transform job directly for a video input (.mp4 or another format)?

If no could you please advice the best practice that might be used for pre-processing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asynchronous inference could be a good option for this use case. There is a blog published by AWS that talks about how you can do this.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/run-computer-vision-inference-on-large-videos-with-amazon-sagemaker-asynchronous-endpoints/